# Putting the data into a list after spiltting the CSV file - Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a `csv` file which I am splitting with delimiter `','`. My target is to iterate through the first column of the entire file and if it matches with the word I have, then I need to have the subsequent values of that particular row into different lists.

Example:

```
AAA,man,2300,
AAA,woman,3300,
BBB,man,2300,
BBB,man,3300,
BBB,man,2300,
BBB,woman,3300,
CCC,woman,2300,
CCC,man,3300,
DDD,man,2300,
```

My code:

```
import csv
datafile = "test.txt"    
with open('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/TEST/Details/'+datafile, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
            print (rows)
```

If I search for a value `BBB`, I want to have the rest of the details of the rows into 3 different lists. (CSV file will always have only 4 columns; the fourth column might be empty sometimes, so we just leave it with a comma)

Sample:

```
list1 = [man, man, man, woman]
list2 = [2300, 3300, 2300, 3300]
list3 = [ , , , ,]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your question is there in your statement: "If I search for a value, say BBB, i want to have the rest of the details of the rows into 3 different lists"

Create empty list:-

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
```

Append values into those list:-

```
for row in reader:
    if ( row[0] == "BBB" ):
        list1.append(row[1])
        list2.append(row[2])
        list3.append(row[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file',sep=',',header=None)
```

Now just use:

```
list1,list2,list3 = df[df[0] == "BBB"].T.values.tolist()
```

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=["AAA","BBB","BBB"],
                  col2=[1,2,3],
                  col3=[4,5,6]))
```

Outputs:

```
(['BBB', 'BBB'], [2, 3], [5, 6]) #list1,list2,list3
```

Comment: does pandas support python 3.6, i dont see the versions for the same

Comment: There is some problem with pandas on pyhton 3.6, else this would be the easy one. thanks.

Comment: when i try to install the pandas, it's failing. i need to check on that. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dev have a look at anaconda. Facilitates a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize three empty list variables and then, in the loop of rows, if c1 matches your value, append the consequent columns to the list.
Edit: OR use pandas at Anton VBR has answered.

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore the part you read data from csv file.

let us begin with a list ( 2d array ). construct a for loop to to search only row1 for your condition - for your example `result vector=[1,2,7,8,9]`. this vector contains list of indices meeting your condition.

now to get the "filtered" list justmake another for loop extracting all other rows indices `result_vector`.